# Xcode project with adMob, project settings excluding adMob for macCatalyst, Clang linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, admob, mac-catalyst

There are problems with macCatalyst compiling needing to exclude adMob Pod objects (adMob do not support macOs) getting error GoogleAppMeasurement' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

- Anyone have a solid *complete* instruction how to exclude the adMob in macCatalyst compiling, would be great?
- I tried to chase the build phase setting of the AdMob Pods for tagets iOs only and just cant find them all, obviously?

*To add the adMob there is a good instruction by Google that includes importing Pods: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start*

Checking the Xcode target mac in the deployment info in the project setup and #if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) excluding the adMob swift code:

- iPhones and iPad targets, Works fine still
- "My Mac" target: Getting Clang link error on the adMob Pod stuff *(GoogleAppMeasurement' for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))*

What I understand, at present there are a huge number of places to set iOS only in the Pod-configuration. Same as this: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/131

- But obviously I can't find all the settings to iOS only (and they were many in Build Phases)
- Yes I can make a new project, but the macCatalyst is a great idea, I like to use it

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this as well. I just made an app for the iPhone/iPad, and would like to get the same app to work on macOS. Which it can, IF i remove the google admod sdk.

Comment: There is an announced new version of the adMob system in 2023, I wait and see.

Comment: I made a Pod-update that worked, among many failed, and I can't see the difference. I don't understand what I did  right? So the documentation on how to do it right is needed. And go on trying and it will work.